# AngularJS: building a chrome extension which will run in an existing app

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-chrome-extension

I'm working on a Chrome extension and I would like to build the content scripts with AngularJS.

Some websites where I want my extension to run are also built with Angular. 
These app can't add any dependency to my own module and it seems not possible to dynamically inject one after application bootstrapped.

Since there is already an app running, I can't bootstrap my own inside the scope of the first one.

Is there a way to achieve that?

Answer (score 3):

The only direction I can think about is running two angular applications, in parallel. The problem is obviously name collision, so you would have to patch angular code and have your own version. This of course is ***completely*** discouraged, but just for the sake of discussion *it seems* that since angular is enclosed in a closure, maybe a simple rename would work, and then you would use the renamed angular. ie maybe something like

change    angular           = window.angular || (window.angular = {}),

to    angular           = window.extAngular || (window.extAngular = {}),

would work, or at least give you a starting point to work on a patch

Comment: So it is possible to run 2 Angular app in the same DOM? Thanks for your answer!

Comment: I never tried it... but theoretically, if you rename the 2nd one, I would think it could work. let us know...

Comment: Since a Chrome extension lives in its own sandbox, I would have guess that name collision will not happen, right? However I've just tried your idea and after renaming any occurence of window.angular to window.extAngular (3 total) it gives me this error: Uncaught TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'element' angular.js:14847
Uncaught TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'bootstrap'

Comment: hmmm... yes if that's the case for chrome extensions then you are right, no need for any changes then. I thought you ran into problems and thats why you asked. About the exception, I'm not sure.. probably need to rename angular in many more places :-\

Comment: I did not find any other occurrences. So I tried without renaming and bootstrapping my app but I got an overflow of $digest cycles. My tab footprint grow like crazy (~1gb) have to crash it.
Sounds not playing well at the moment.